An extra cross-term in the upper bound, how to remove it?
I was reading the book "Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes". There is a problem in this book:
For any pair of random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$, one has $\|\xi+\eta\|_{2,1}^2 \leq 4\|\xi\|_{2,1}^2+$ $4\|\eta\|_{2,1}^2$.
The following is what I've tried so far:
First, the norm $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}$ is defined as: $\|\cdot\|_{2,1}=\int_0^\infty\sqrt{P(|\cdot|>x)}dx$.
Second, \begin{aligned}
& P(|\varepsilon+\eta|>x) \leqslant P\left(|\varepsilon|>\frac{x}{2}\right)+P\left(|\eta|>\frac{x}{2}\right) \\
& \sqrt{P(|\varepsilon+\eta|>x)} \leqslant \sqrt{P\left(|\varepsilon|>\frac{x}{2}\right)}+\sqrt{P\left(|\eta|>\frac{x}{2}\right)} \\
 \Rightarrow & \|\varepsilon+\eta\|_{2,1} \leqslant \int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{P\left(|\varepsilon|>\frac{x}{2}\right)} d x+\int_0^{\infty} \sqrt{P\left(|\eta|>\frac{x}{2}\right)}dx=2\|\varepsilon\|_{2,1}+2\|\eta\|_{2,1} \\
\Rightarrow & \|\varepsilon+\eta\|_{2,1}^2 \leqslant 4\|\varepsilon\|_{2,1}^2+4\|\eta\|_{2,1}^2+8\|\varepsilon\|_{2,1}\cdot\|\eta\|_{2,1}
\end{aligned}
My question is, how do I remove the cross-term on the right?
